# No voice for both incoming and outgoing calls

Tags: 8.1, calls, nokia-lumia-630

I recently bought a Lumia 630 *(dual-sim variant)* and I am facing this issue from the 2nd day of using. Sometimes I am not able to hear voice while making an incoming or an outgoing call. Performing Factory Reset seems the only solution and it does solve the issue for few days then the issue occurs again.

Is there any solution rather than performing a Factory Reset every time?

Comment: I am facing the same issue! Nokia care is useless. All we can hope is nokia/microsoft acknowledge this issue and give us the possible timeline for the update! Nokia is making me regret my decision!

Comment: @Viverk - I am also trying to get this matter in Nokia/Microsoft attention, but I am afraid they are not even acknowledging the issue! - https://twitter.com/NokiaHelps/status/477748629118013440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Lumia 630 replaced twice.(-_-) It works fine now.